# How to I set up highlight with search word in VSCodeVim when press shift + *

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

In vim, I am able to highlight the search word by moving my cursor to word and press `shift + *`. How can I perform the same in visual studio code with VSCodeVim extension?

Answer (score 3):

set `vim.hlsearch=true` in setting.json

Comment: sigh. wrong, non-JSON syntax.

Answer (score 0):

"set vim.hlsearch=true" setting in settings.json is worded like this in my vscode version (1.76.2):

```
"vim.hlsearch": true,
```